# Confusing results with typeof and isNaN with (1 + undefined) operation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Consider the following operation:

```
typeof (1 + undefined) => "number"
```

and now this operation:

```
isNaN(1 + undefined) => true
```

typeof states that the result of (1+undefined) should be a number.

While, the operation of if (1+undefined) is not a number is true.

How is this possible?

NOTE: I tested this in console of google chrome if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: `NaN` is a number.

The term "not a number" doesn't mean "not a member of the type `number` in JavaScript".  It's a term from the relevant floating-point specification, in which a set of bit patterns is collectively used to designate values that are "not numbers"; that is, the bit patterns are not valid.

It's somewhat unfortunate that JavaScript was designed such that certain operations that have numerically meaningless results yield `NaN`, since the point of `NaN` in the spec is to designate values to be *avoided*. It's too late to revisit that decision however.

The global `isNaN()` function always attempts to convert its argument to `number` before performing the test. Thus, it's often used to check if a string value contains digits that can be interpreted as a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

Because  `typeof (1 + undefined)` is `typeof NaN`, and

```
typeof NaN === "number" //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `(1 + undefined)` result in `NaN` you get that behaviour. Check the examples below:

```js
var value = 1 + undefined;
console.log('value for (1 + undefined) is ' + value);

var result1 = typeof (1 + undefined);
console.log('typeof (1 + undefined) is ' + result1);

//this result2
var result2 = isNaN(1 + undefined);
console.log('result of isNaN(1 + undefined) is ' + result2);

//is same as 
result2 = isNaN(NaN); //as 1 + undefined is NaN
console.log('result of isNaN(NaN) is ' + result2);
```